# Using MOD in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I'm just starting coding and programming and white trying to complete an exercise I noted that the MOD operation doesn't work with variables.
Can someone explain to me why? And also give me some tips on how to do it? Thank you.

```
program Stack_Overflow;
var
 sec, hour, day: real;


begin

    WriteLn('Insert a number of seconds.');
    ReadLn (sec);


    hour := sec div 3600;
    writeln (hour);

readln;
end.
```

Comment: Please add an expample to help us to help you

Comment: MOD certainly does work with variables.   Could you show us your code?

Comment: The variables were all right! The editor clearly pointed out that the mod operation was the issue.

Comment: It's good that you can't post photos, because we want the code as text, not as a screenshot. Please post a [mcve] and the error message that you get when you try to run the code.

Comment: If you want help here, you are supposed to include your code and any error messages as text, not as screenshots.  You should copy and paste your code into the Question editor, select it if necessary and then press Ctrl-K.  That will indent it by four spaces, which the SO screen will use to show it as code rather than plain text.

Comment: @JJJ Oh ok sorry I'm still new here... I updated it (right now I'm on my phone, so I don't have the full project but this is the part that is wrong). Here the error appears as '"Internal Interpreter Error: Unspecified"

Comment: @MartynA Oh ok sorry I'm still new here... I updated it (right now I'm on my phone, so I don't have the full project but this is the part that is wrong). Here the error appears as '"Internal Interpreter Error: Unspecified"

Comment: Which Pascal are you using?  Btw, you didn't include your `MOD` code, which is what we need to see.

Comment: @MartynA The same happens with DIV. I tried both and the same thing happens... Pascal Zim

Comment: `DIV` and `MOD` operators works only on integers, not on floating point numbers.

Comment: @LURD I should pay more attention honestly, thank you.

Comment: What @LURD says is the likely explanation of your problem: you need to declare your variables as of type `integer` rather than `real`.  I hadn't seen Pascal Zim before, so I downloaded the most recent version and tried your code in it, but its IDE just hung when I told it to execute the code.  Unless you absolutely have to use ZIM, I suggest you take a look at [Lazarus](https://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=downloads) which includes the FreePascal compiler.

Comment: @MartynA I have both, but since it was an easy project i just started doing it on ZIM because I don't understand a lot of functionalities on Lazarus

Comment: Well, Lazarus would have told you `project1.lpr(...) Error: Operator is not overloaded: "Real" mod "SmallInt"``

Comment: For simple console more programs, just choose Simple Program. It should work fine, and be much easier to use than ZIM. It also gives much better error messages.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  Indeed, and it won't just hang when you give it something indigestible to execute.  Actually, I'm not even sure Zim is a compiler rather than an interpreter (my Portugese isn't too hot).

Comment: @MartynA: ""Internal Interpreter Error: Unspecified" sounds indeed like an interpreter. Hmmm...

Answer (score 2):

`DIV` and `MOD` operators works only on integers, not on floating point numbers.

Just declare:

```
var
  sec, hour, day: integer;
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: Well yes, as far as one can go with ZIM. <g> +1.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, can't be worse than punching cards for the univac, where I started learning programming.